# R code for resource allocation optimization with constraint

Tags: r, linear-programming, maximize

I am looking for a solution to optimize a resource allocation problem using r. The total resources as denoted in the equation as Qt to be distributed over two different demands i and j which provide total benefit as it is given in objective function. The total resources for 12 months periods are Qt = c(27,24,29,86,167,395,490,512,436,218,70,37). The objective function and constraint equations are as following

[image: Objective function and constraints]

Can anyone please help me solving this problem using sequential quadratic programming (SQP) method and/or any other suitable optimization technique in R?

Comment: Qi has lower marginal cost than Qj... for the solution just choose the highest Qi that satisfies the constraints.  `Qi = pmax(72, pmin(Qt-50, 1000)); Qj = Qt-Qi`.

Comment: @sirallen Thanks, Sirallen. I understand what you are suggesting. I changed my problem and put a more realistic one where the marginal benefit of two demands intersects each other. I know I can still apply your suggestion by looking at the intersection point, but I would like to know an optimization solution in r. Please see my corrected post.

Comment: SQP is used for nonlinear problems. Your problem is linear so a linear LP solver would be more appropriate, Of course this problem is so simple you can solve it without any solver at all..